# getting data from an array of objects inside array JSON data

Tags: json, angular

I have trouble taking data from an API set. The body if viewed in Postman / Insomnia is as follows

```
{
   "responses": {
        "log": [
             {
                "id": 123,
                "date": "2022-01-01T01:12:12.000Z",
                "type": "online",
                "details": [{
                        "detailId": "123-1",
                        "note": "success",
                     }]
              },
              {
                "id": 124,
                "date": "2022-01-01T01:12:12.000Z",
                "type": "offline",
                "details": [{
                        "detailId": "123-2",
                        "note": "failed",
                     }]
              }
         ]
      }
}
```

I want to take all data from log, as well from details. I used

```
adapt(item: any) {
return {
   id: item.id,
   date: item.date,
   details: {
      detailId: item.details.detailId,
      note: item.details.note,
   },
};
}
```

this returns id and date just fine. I also have a query to filter it based on type (online or offline), basically adding `&type=` into the API. It works for the online, but it returns detailId is undefined for offline (I used the same body, adapter and API minus the query for both data)

Comment: `details` is an array of objects, not a single object. Try `item.details[0].detailId`.

Comment: @fubar thank you!! it works for most of the data, but somehow a data still returns them as undefined even though the body is exactly the same

Comment: Why you adapt item to an item ? Just return responsable.log

Comment: @ahmadridhwan, can you update your question to include an example that does work and one that doesn't?

Comment: @fubar already did, hope it's sufficient enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, apparently to make sure that I can get every value is to add ? after the [0], so it should be

```
details: {
      detailId: item.details[0]?.detailId,
      note: item.details[0]?.note,
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

details is an array of object if you want to adapt it you need to do it iteratively.

```
adapt(item: any) {
const details = item.details.map(d => {detailId: d.id, note: d.note, …});
return {
   id: item.id,
   date: item.date,
   details
  };
}
```

Comment: I already have a model, so the adapt is into the model (I didn't show it here because the error doesn't come from the models, rather from adapter and API (cannot read undefined property)